# How to handle the below jQuery in Angular method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The simple jQuery below will not run in my angular web app. It runs in the console but is not read when included as external file. Other script in same file runs, this however does not. Any thoughts? How could I re-write the below using the correct Angular way (I'm currently new to angular).

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
   $('input.ng-pristine').show(); //class selector for the div to show
});
```

Comment: did you put your code in document ready?

Comment: why do you want to do that in an angular app? why don't you use ng-click directive?

Comment: Why not handle this in angular logic?

Comment: @JordiRuiz could you suggest how the above can be done using that angular method?

Comment: You'd have something like having an `ng-click` on the button and `ng-show` or `ng-hide` on the input ...?

Comment: *"how to use jQuery outside angular"* **don't.**

Comment: common click hide show functions should not need jquery. the only time where you might possibly consider using jquery is when there is a plugin that you cannot find in angular, and do not wish to rewrite in angular. then you can consider wrapping up jquery code in angular directive

Comment: @KevinB Ehh.. not always a hard and fast rule. There are certain edge cases where it makes sense.

Comment: I disagree, but to each their own.

Comment: Not meaning to be rude but you should really look into basic Angular such as: http://www.angularjsbook.com/angular-basics/chapters/basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea behind how you would do this in angular is like so

```
//your button
<button id="button" ng-click="clickButton()">your button </button>
//your input to hide
<input ng-show="!hideInput" />
```

And in the controller

```
 $scope.clickButton = function() {
      $scope.hideInput = !$scope.hideInput;
 };
```

Now, I don't know if you have special use cases for show and hiding this, but this button will toggle the show/hide as is. If you are toggling it on and off you can simplify it even further like so :

```
 <button id="button" ng-click="hideInput = !hideInput">your button </button>
```

This might not work for you if you don't want it to toggle, but the idea is $scope.hideInput is a boolean which controls ng-show or ng-hide on the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an angular directive

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" ng-click="myFunction()">


// In your angular controller
$scope.myFunction = function() {
   // do something
};
```

Answer (score -2):

The right way is to use angular Directive's

**Edit:**

angular `ng-click` and `ng-show` will do the job:

**Code Sample:**

in html file:

```
<body ng-app="example.module">
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <button id='button' ng-click="show()"> show it! </button>
      <input class="pristine" ng-show="visible">
   </div>
</body>
```

in js file :

```
angular.module('example.module')
   .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

     $scope.visible = false;

     $scope.show = function(){
        $scope.visible = true;
      }

})
```